# How to end my sick note?

Tags: professionalism, applications, email, sickness, leave-of-absence

I am just a trainee at a company currently on probation period. 
I am sick today and this is the short email I have written.

Dear Sir,

Due to suffering from cold and fever, I won't be able to attend the office today.

--
Jake

Is this okay?

Since I am just a trainee I didn't want to go in much depth.
Should I put Thanks or Sincerely something before my name?
If yes then what should I write 
Any improvisations?

Comment: Instead of downvoting, would have appreciated one word comment

Comment: "Dear Sir" is a very different level of formality than ending your email with simply your first name. Either make the first part less formal (by saying e.g. "Hey {first name}") or make the last part more formal (by adding something along the lines of "Thanks in advance for understanding. Yours Sincerely" and including your last name as well). I'd opt for the former when sending an email to a coworker or direct manager, but I don't know your company culture.

Comment: @Dukeling I already sent it. Next time will keep that in mind.

Comment: Personally I think its better to ring and speak in person if possible.

Comment: the Op is simply asking **how to end the business communication**.  The best way is:  **"kindly, Jake**   that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something people, in my opinion, think too much into. When calling in sick, just do the following:

1. Follow company procedure (whether that's emailing your manager, or calling the front desk, whatever)
2. Provide the minimum applicable information. The company shouldn't (and likely doesn't) care why, just that you won't be available. e.g. "Hi, {your name} here, I'm going to take today off as {type of leave} leave. Thanks" (Where {your name} is the name people know you by in the company, and {type of leave} is the applicable leave type, usually sick or carer's)

If they need more information than that, they can always contact you.

Comment: What am I thanking him for?

Comment: Maybe that's a cultural thing which doesn't apply in your area. I would say you would be thanking them for their time and understanding, but really it's more of a social custom in my area (Australia).

Comment: Hmm. I just find it a bit weird writing thanks here. Since it's not like I am asking for his permission for leave. But yeah maybe for his time and understanding I should write it. Though I already sent the email without thanks. Hope he doesn't get offended.

Comment: I'm sure it would be fine without the "thanks". Please consider marking the answer as correct if you think this answered your question.

Comment: You can interpret the courtesy 'thanks' as 'Thanks for your attention' or 'Thanks for handling this further' (since the receiver of the message will have to give it some time, i.e. reading and probably doing some administrative follow-up).

Comment: Honestly, if you are down with fever, probably most people would excuse a slight lack of formality/thanks/whatever they might have expected anyway, so do not overthink this.

Comment: thanks is **completely wrong**.  it is particularly wrong in Australia.  it's actually implying that person B is *doing something for you* and, even worse, you are  *assuming they are going to do it*.  you *could* say "thanks in advance if you agree" but that would be nonsensical here.  do **not** end with "thanks".  end with "kindly, "

Comment: If you do want to be obsequious (I don't see why) end with "Sorry for the inconvenience Steve, kindly Jake".  But don't do that, just end "kindly Jake".

Comment: @Fattie How is it "particularly wrong in Australia"? As an Australian, I find it to be exceedingly common to put thanks on the end of almost any communication. Largely just as a custom, not to actually thank anyone for following instructions in the communication.

Comment: hey @Maybe_Factor, you could be right; I haven't lived or worked there for awhile. It would come across as snarky in a general business context.

Comment: @Fattie. Exactly my thoughts!